# Iterating over rows in a DataTableReader with foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, foreach

Can i use `foreach (DataRow row in r)`?

I have this code:

```
    conStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Database.mdf") + ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    string sqlStr = "Select * FROM Msgs WHERE Reciver='"+Reciver+"'";
    SqlDataAdapter daObj = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, conStr);
    DataSet dsObj = new DataSet();
    daObj.Fill(dsObj);
    DataTableReader r = dsObj.Tables[0].CreateDataReader();
    foreach (DataRow row in r)
```

i ran debug and it stopped on the line of the foreach and gave me this error:

`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' to type 'System.Data.DataRow`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `foreach` is trying to cast a `DataRow` from the `DataTableReader` which it cannot.

A `DataTableReader` *reads* rows, but does not *have* rows.  It can only read over the rows in a `DataTable` one by one.  Rafa's answer on this post goes over the best use of `DataTableReader`.

If you must use a `DataTableReader` then just put it in a `while` loop:

```
while (r.Read())
{
    //Access r with r["columnName"]
}
```

If you want the `foreach`, just loop over the rows in the `DataTable` itself:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dsObj.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    //Do something with the rows
}
```

In terms of performance, I would think that the `foreach` would be better simply because it does not require you to instantiate another object (the `DataTableReader`), you also get write access to the rows if you want to modify their contents.

Comment: Good effort with proper explanations. +1 for that.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `foreach` you can use:

```
while (r.Read())
{
     // r[0], r[1], ... or r["Name"] will give you access to fields
}
```

See [this example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1sxt4e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

`DataTableReader` contains `DataTable` objects in the form of one or more read-only, forward-only result sets. You can use [DataTableReader.NextResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader.nextresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to navigate through their records.

Example from the previous link documentation

```
using (DataTableReader reader = new DataTableReader(
           new DataTable[] { customerDataTable, productDataTable }))
{
    // Print the contents of each of the result sets. 
    do
    {
        PrintColumns(reader);
    } while (reader.NextResult());
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `PrintColumns(reader)` and `NextResult`:  This is the proper way to use a `DataTableReader`.

Answer (score -2):

```
onStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Database.mdf") + ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"; string sqlStr = "Select * FROM Msgs WHERE Reciver='"+Reciver+"'"; SqlDataAdapter daObj = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, conStr); DataSet dsObj = new DataSet(); daObj.Fill(dsObj); 
// DataTableReader r = dsObj.Tables[0].CreateDataReader();//



 foreach (DataRow dr in dsObj.Tables[0].rows)
{
enter code here`
/.........
}
```

Comment: First of all this is a duplicate of an answer from quite a bit earlier.  Second you didn't format your answer whatsoever, or offer an explanation as to *why* this answer works.